# Weird SSH behaviour

Tags: debian, ssh, key-authentication

I have 3 computers. All have SSH running and All have No password mode on, PKI only.

The first has a keyPair used for SSH access to the other two, call this machine A.

Therefore, both B and C have A's public key in their `authorized_keys`, and A can ssh to either without a password.

However, C doesn't have B's public key in it's `authorized_keys` file, yet, when I ssh from A -> B, and then SSH from B -> C, C let's the ssh session connect without a password.

**Why is this happening?**

Surely C should deny the session request from B, despite the fact that I'm SSH'd from A into B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look after `ssh-agent` and `AllowAgentForwarding`.

Your private key on A must be loaded in your local `ssh-agent`. And `AllowAgentForwarding` must be activated, so that the challenge generated on C to B is forwarded by B to A (in a chain of trust). And the `ssh-agent` on A is replying to the crypto challenge of C relayed by B which authentifies you on C and let you enter in it from B.

Disallow `AllowAgentForwarding` in sshd on B and C and it wont occur anymore.

Comment: thank you my friend.

Comment: please validate my answer if it satisfies you :P

Comment: done and upvoted too.